# Missing Unicode codecs on kivy/Python on Android?

Tags: android, python, unicode, kivy

I have a program running under kivy that works fine on Windows but fails on opening a file on Android (1.8.0 on both platforms). The odd thing is that the error message indicates it's trying to decode ASCII when I'm plainly asking for utf-8; also the file doesn't have a 0xFF character anywhere in it - I checked with the `od` utility.

The code:

```
try:
    Logger.info('Mark: opening file ' + repr(filename))
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf_8') as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip(u'\r\n').lstrip(codecs.BOM) for line in f]
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    Logger.info('Mark: utf8 load failed: ' + str(e))
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip(u'\r\n') for line in f]
```

The log file:

```
[INFO              ] Mark: opening file '/mnt/sdcard/My Files/Documents/DVDs.txt'
[INFO              ] Mark: utf8 load failed: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
[INFO              ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 295, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:     app.run()
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 792, in run
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 481, in runTouchApp
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 381, in mainloop
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 287, in _mainloop
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 321, in idle
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 422, in tick
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 537, in _process_events
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 309, in tick
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 266, in select_file_part2
[WARNING           ] stderr:     with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 884, in open
[WARNING           ] stderr: LookupError: unknown encoding: cp1252
```

**Edit:** I put in some debugging code to go through the [entire list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) and found that all were missing except `ascii`, `latin_1`, and the various `utf` codecs.

Comment: FYI, for automatic BOM handling use `utf-8-sig`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you've successfully figured out why I was getting a decode error, thanks much. But that still doesn't explain why `cp1252` is missing. I guess I had two different errors.

Comment: Maybe the encoding isn't provided on Android.  Does Python's `Lib\encodings\cp1252.py` exist?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I haven't found the install directory for Python yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the try/except and look at the real exception.  `codecs.BOM` is a byte string `\xff\xfe` and it is being coerced into Unicode using the default `ascii` codec:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.BOM
'\xff\xfe'
>>> u'test'.lstrip(codecs.BOM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```