# Kivy (python-for-android) missing codecs

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, kivy, codec

I have just ran into problem of missing codecs, that has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794587/missing-unicode-codecs-on-kivy-python-on-android), but the solution provided there fixed other problem, preventing the original one to show. However I'm experiencing the same thing now and there's no workaround this time.

I have HTML page in windows-1250 encoding. I'm using `htmlRequest = requests.get(url)` to fetch it and I have to explicitly specify encoding as `htmlRequest.encoding = 'windows-1250'`. Then reading `htmlRequest.text` should properly decode the content and it indeed does work on both Win and Linux, but on Android I only get white spaces instead of special characters.

I wondered why, so I tried to show original `htmlRequest.content` which worked, but on `htmlRequest.content.decode('windows-1250')` (which is the same as `htmlRequest.text`) the app raises an exception: `"LookupError: unknown encoding: windows-1250"`. I also tried the name `cp1250` but while again working for both Win and Linux, it didn't change the situation for Android.

Therefore I believe that these codecs are really missing and asking for help in solving this. I can't really change encoding of that page and if I'm missing the right codec, how can I decode it properly? Or are there any other ways to do this?

**Edit:** As explained by Ryan, white-listing should help, but I'm building apk using Buildozer. Does it have any option for that (using `buildozer.spec` file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra codecs are stripped (blacklisted) from the python-for-android build in order to save space. You can solve this problem by whitelisting the codec you need. Create a file (probably called whitelist.txt) or add to your existing whitelist the following line:

```
encodings/cp1250.pyo
```

Then provide the whitelist file to `build.py` with the `--whitelist` argument.

---

For buildozer, you can add this to the `android.p4a_whitelist` value in buildozer.spec.

Comment: The problem is that I'm building with buildozer (probably should have noted that, but I didn't know they were stripped in first place..), I'll try to look if there's any option to specify codec whitelist in buildozer.spec, but I think it will require messing with code.

Comment: It looks like `android.p4a_whitelist` should do the trick.... but FYI I don't use buildozer, I use p4a directly. :)

Comment: Great! I missed that at first as it was commented. Worked without flaw, although I had to first clean and then build platform again. You might want to add this to your answer so it's more visible, but I'm marking this as answered, thanks.